# Javascript Date Returning NaN undefined NaN

Tags: javascript

I am pulling modified dates from a SharePoint library and using the below to convert it:

```
    function convertSPDate(d) {
    // split apart the date and time
    var xDate = d.split("")[0];
    var xTime = d.split(" ")[1];

    // split apart the hour, minute, & second
    var xTimeParts = xTime.split(":");
    var xHour = xTimeParts[0];
    var xMin = xTimeParts[1];


    // split apart the year, month, & day
    var xDateParts = xDate.split("-");
    var xMonth = xDateParts[1]-1;    
    var xDay = xDateParts[2];
    var xYear = xDateParts[0];  

    var dDate = new Date(xYear, xMonth, xDay, xHour, xMin);
    return dDate;
}
```

And then formatting it using:

```
function getformattedDate(d){
var month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "October", "Nov" , "Dec"];
var getConvertedDate = d;
return formattedDate =  getConvertedDate.getDate() +" "+month[getConvertedDate.getMonth()] +" "+getConvertedDate.getFullYear();     
}
```

I'm then trying to display this date on a page for different items using:

```
var getDate = getformattedDate(convertSPDate(getFilteredItems[i].modified));
```

However this is just returning NaN undefined NaN - any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: The first split looks wrong... Should be space?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I see a lot spots where a console.log could narrow down this issue

Comment: This question would be improved a great deal by including sample input and expected output.

Comment: Did you try a simple `function convertSPDate(d) { return new Date(d) }`? because your format seems to be `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and that seems to work just fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @trincot - was a very simple solution and one I completely overlooked!

The first split was wrong and simply needed a space...

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) this is a one-liner :

`var d = moment("2017-06-06 19:15").format("D MMM YYYY");`

[jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/xasepikoze/edit?js,console)